# Printer does not work after Win 8.1 upgrade

Tags: windows-8.1-upgrade

I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. My printer now doesn't work (attached to the desktop via USB). I then installed the latest HP drivers for 8.1 and it still isn't working. On the test page it says that the printer spool is full but there are no outstanding print jobs shown. I also use the HP 940C printer connected to another computer on a different wireless network. Windows 8.1 finds it but will not print either. What's happened? It all worked before the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the print spooler files:

```
NET STOP SPOOLER
```

Navigate to "%WINDIR%\system32\spool\printers", delete all files in this folder.

```
NET START SPOOLER
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with HP all-in-one photosmart c309g. Uninstalled all HP drivers from control panel-Programs and features. Restarted and then reinstalled drivers. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install the drivers again following the instructions below

1: Remove the printer

2: Use the command below to remove the printer drivers completely

```
      printui.exe /s /t2
```

3: Restart the computer

4: Clear the printer spool as suggested by [Debra](https://superuser.com/a/664089/270195)

5: Add the printer again